# What is the point of connect in React-redux?

Tags: react-redux

I have this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class WeatherList extends Component {
  renderWeather(cityData) {
    const name = cityData.city.name;

    return (
      <tr key={name}>
        <td> {name} </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Temp</th>
            <th>Pressure</th>
            <th>Humidity</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ weather }) { // es6 shorthand. it's as if state was teh argument and { weather: state.weather } was in the return
  return { weather };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WeatherList);
```

On the last line, why can't I just write `export default WeatherList`? The state is available inside the component because of the `mapStateToProps` function right? So what is the point of the `connect`?

For more context, my reducer is this:

```
import { FETCH_WEATHER } from "../actions/index";

export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_WEATHER:
    // return state.concat([ action.payload.data ]); // don't use push. concat creates a new array, while push mutates the old one. YOu want to create a new array, not mutate the old one.
    return  [ action.payload.data, ...state ];
  }
  return state;
}
```

Comment: The name `mapStateToProps` is just a convention, it doesn't do anything by itself, it's the connect that is doing all the job of providing the state. Replace `mapStateToProps` by `foo`or directly inline a function in the connect call, it will work the same.

Comment: How do you do it directly in line?

Comment: `export default connect(({ weather}) => ({ weather}))(WeatherList);`